# htaccess - subdomain as GET parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have the following already in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But I want to add a rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+).example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)% http://example.com/?name=%1&type=$1 [R,L]
```

But without it binding to `example.com` and it must work on any domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%2.com/?name=%1 [R=301,L]
```

rewrites `http://subdomain.domain.com` to `http://www.domain.com/?name=subdomain`

to combine the two try something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%2.com/index.php?route=$1&name=%1 [R=301,L]
```

that will redirect `http://subdomain.domain.com/hello-world` to `http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=hello-world&name=subdomain`

Comment: But how to combine these two rules like on this example:
http://subd.domain.com/folder1/folder2/ = 
http://domain.com/index.php?domain=subd&route=folder1/folder2/

Comment: - URL in browser should not become a http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=hello-world&name=subdomain , it must stay http://subdomain.domain.com/hello-world
- I don't need www prefiix

Comment: come on, just remove the `www.` part then - that you should be able to figure our yourself

Comment: @user1247574, In this case you need to do an **Internal Redirect** -> just remove the R=301 flag.  (But remember that this won't appear to work at first because your browser will have cached these 301s)

Comment: Where to put this ?

Can any one give me detail steps, do we have to add subdomain from cpanel as well ?